# GridView data is not being obtained

Tags: c#, asp.net, events, gridview

This is my code in .cs file :

```
 protected void GridView2_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        name = e.Row.Cells[0].Text;

    }
```

And this is my .aspx code for GridView:

```
 <asp:GridView ID = "GridView2" runat ="server" DataSourceID = "sourceProducts" AutoGenerateColumns = "False"  AllowSorting="True" Width="100%" OnRowDataBound="GridView2_RowDataBound">     
                        <Columns>              
                            <asp:BoundField DataField = "resultId" HeaderText = "Result Id" /> 
                            <asp:BoundField DataField = "runOwner" HeaderText = "Owner"  />

                        </Columns>
                    </asp:GridView>
```

I want to obtain value of first column that is resultId .

Comment: Anyone who can help or knows the reason why it is not happening?

Comment: This is what is required :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28711384/how-to-get-value-of-a-gridview-cell-in-this-scenario

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be reading the value from the datasource on the RowDataBoundEvent not the cells.

Example:

```
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
         DataRowView d = (DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem;
         name = d["resultId"].ToString();
    }
```

Comment: Please define doesn't work.  Are you getting an error?