# How to get value of a gridview cell in this scenario

Tags: c#, asp.net, events, gridview

I have a link button inside a gridView as below :

```
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Analyze">
                                 <ItemTemplate>
                                   <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" Text="Analyze"  runat="server"  OnClick="LinkButton1_Click"  />                                 
                                 </ItemTemplate>
                             </asp:TemplateField>
```

I have the LinkButton1_Click function as below :

```
 protected void LinkButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {     

        testtb.Text = name;
        Console.WriteLine(name);
     }
```

This variable "name" is the first column of the GridView.I am obtaining the value for "name" as below:

```
protected void UnanalysedGV_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            DataRowView d = (DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem;
            name = d["resultId"].ToString();

        }

    }
```

I want that on click of the link button the value of first column in that row of gridview becomes the text for the textbox testtb.

Somehow,the value for name remains null.

**EDIT**

I found out that probably RowDataBound isn't the correct event for my requirements because I need the value for each row.

So I removed the RowDataBound function.

I guess I have to handle this inside LinkButton1_Click itself.

I added this line to the function :

```
name = UnanalysedGV.SelectedRow.Cells[1].Text;
```

Still doesn't work.
Does anyone have any idea ?

Comment: try this http://www.dotnetbull.com/2013/05/how-to-handle-click-event-of-linkbutton.html

Comment: It worked.Please post it as an answer so that I can mark it as correct

Comment: great, yes ofcource. i will post it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using two approaches as mentioned below.

> Handle click event of linkbutton through event bubbling code -

```
<asp:GridView AutoGenerateColumns="false" runat="server" ID="grdCustomPagging" OnRowCommand="grdCustomPagging_RowCommand">
   <Columns>
       <asp:BoundField DataField="RowNumber" HeaderText="RowNumber" />
       <asp:BoundField DataField="DealId" HeaderText="DealID" />
       <asp:BoundField DataField="Dealtitle" HeaderText="DealTitle" />
       <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="View">
        <ItemTemplate>
       <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="lnkView" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("DealId") %>'
         CommandName="VIEW">View Deal</asp:LinkButton>
         </ItemTemplate>
       </asp:TemplateField>
   </Columns>
</asp:GridView>

protected void grdCustomPagging_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "VIEW")
    {
        LinkButton lnkView = (LinkButton)e.CommandSource;
        string dealId = lnkView.CommandArgument;
    }
}
```

> Handle click event of linkbutton directly click event code -

```
<asp:GridView AutoGenerateColumns="false" runat="server" ID="grdCustomPagging">
   <Columns>
       <asp:BoundField DataField="RowNumber" HeaderText="RowNumber" />
       <asp:BoundField DataField="DealId" HeaderText="DealID" />
       <asp:BoundField DataField="Dealtitle" HeaderText="DealTitle" />
       <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="View">
        <ItemTemplate>
       <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="lnkView" OnClick="lnkView_Click">View Deal</asp:LinkButton>
         </ItemTemplate>
       </asp:TemplateField>
   </Columns>
</asp:GridView>

protected void lnkView_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow grdrow = (GridViewRow)((LinkButton)sender).NamingContainer;
    string rowNumber = grdrow.Cells[0].Text;
    string dealId = grdrow.Cells[1].Text;
    string dealTitle = grdrow.Cells[2].Text;
}
```

Hope this helps.